# Sending SMS with Fuel-sdk PHP

Tags: marketing-cloud, php

I'm trying to send a SMS to a single number using the PHP sdk

I've had a look at this https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/sms-api-scenario-guide.html

but cant find a PHP SDK.

anyone know the best way to send a sms to a single SMS. the body of the message will contain a unqiue code for each number.